# Replace null value with default text

Tags: c#, default, isnull

I know this question has been asked many times, but I have the following piece of code that I am trying to use to default null values. Can someone please help me. I tried this code but instead of giving me "NO DATA" for the null values, it doesnt display anything. Not sure where I am going wrong.

**More Detail**: This code does not replace null values with "NO DATA" string. What is wrong here? What do I need to change in order for it to display "NO DATA"?

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        DataSet dataset = GetDataSet.Get(context);
        foreach (DataTable dt in dataset.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (row["USER_COMMENT"] is System.DBNull)
                {
                    ConvertNullToEmptyString(dt);
                    Console.WriteLine("In if");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("out if");
                }
            }
        }
         TransformResult.Set(context, dataset);
    }


    private static string ConvertNullToEmptyString(DataTable element)
    {
        if (element.Rows[0]["USER_COMMENT"] == DBNull.Value || element.Rows[0]["USER_COMMENT"] == null)
        {
            return "NO DATA";
        }
        else
        {
            return element.Rows[0]["USER_COMMENT"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ConvertNullToEmptyString` seemingly _returns_ "NO DATA", but you're never using the return value.

Comment: yes i think you are right how should i do this?

Comment: Can't test atm, but I'd try plain `var user_comment = row.Field<string>("USER_COMMENT") ?? "NO DATA";` to get the value of either `USER_COMMENT` or the string `NO DATA` if DBNull. Replacing the value in the actual datarow is fairly slow and afaik not necessary.

Comment: I found the answer thanks to your suggestion. IF you want to post your comment as answer, I can mark it as an answer. TY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of extra function there. You just have to insert the "No DATA" in the loop like below

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (row["USER_COMMENT"] is System.DBNull)
            {
                row["USER_COMMENT"] = "NO DATA";
                Console.WriteLine("In if");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("out if");
            }
        }
```

Comment: This solution works very well. I am not sure if there are any additional checks I need to do, but for the time, this is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: To check the NULL value this condition is enough. But if you want to check empty string value also, you just have to add one more condition to the if like  if (row["USER_COMMENT"] is System.DBNull || row["USER_COMMENT"] == string.Empty) .

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do

```
String stringtocompare;

     if(String.isnullorwhitespace(stringtocompare)){
         stringtocompare = "No VALUE";
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple things that might help:

You probably want to change this:

```
foreach (DataTable dt in dataset.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
        ...
```

to this:

```
foreach (DataTable dt in dataset.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
        ...
```

Or else you will only be querying 1 table in your loop.

Also, I'd use [String.IsNullOrEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to interrogate the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a second function to do it, try something like this:

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context) {
  DataSet dataset = GetDataSet.Get(context);
  foreach(DataTable dt in dataset.Tables) {
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
      row["USER_COMMENT"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["USER_COMMENT"].ToString()) ? "NO DATA" : row["USER_COMMENT"];
    }
  }
  TransformResult.Set(context, dataset);
}
```

But, with a second function to convert, it would look something like this:

```
protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context) {
  DataSet dataset = GetDataSet.Get(context);
  foreach(DataTable dt in dataset.Tables) {
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
      row["USER_COMMENT"] = ConvertNullToEmptyString(row["USER_COMMENT"]);
    }
  }
  TransformResult.Set(context, dataset);
}

private static object ConvertNullToEmptyString(object element) {
  if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(element.ToString())) {
    return "NO DATA";
  } else {
    return element;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use empty string instead of null

```
if(row["USER_COMMENT"] == string.Empty)
```

Comment: But row["USER_COMMENT"] is of type object. I am getting an error

Comment: Sorry but this does not seem to work. It just exits out of the loop without checking the condition

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
private static string ConvertNullToEmptyString(DataTable element)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Rows[0]["USER_COMMENT"]))
        {
            return "NO DATA";
        }
        else
        {
            return element.Rows[0]["USER_COMMENT"].ToString();
        }
    }
```